# Undefined offset: 1 in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to return this function but i don't know how to fix it.

**Laravel Controller**

```
public static function downlines($userid,$level){
      
        $level = '';
         static $array = array();
   
        $select = DB::table('stages')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('spillover_id',$userid)
        ->get();
      
  
            $level++;
            foreach($select as $value){
                $userid = $value->member_id;
            $array[$level] .= $userid.',';
                 self::downlines($userid, $level);
            }
               

            
         return $array;
            }
```

ERROR **Undefined offset: 1**

```
$array[$level] .= $userid.',';
```

How to let it's work ?

Comment: I can't understand something, why you pass parameter `$level`, and  at the first line you set `level` to empty string and then you try to increment the value?

Comment: You are concatenating string to array without initializing $array[$level].

Comment: Thank you. I pass parameter  `$level` = 0 but **ERROR Undefined offset: 1** again

Comment: @Sacc you overwrite the $level parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a new array key so the "." needs to be removed.
Your $level++ needs to be inside the foreach , and $level needs to be 0 not ''

```
     foreach($select as $value){
         $level++;
         $userid = $value->member_id;
         $array[$level] = $userid.',';
         self::downlines($userid, $level);
    
     }
```

Or do you want all userids in $array[1]? In that case you need to set the array key to a empty string first:

```
        $array[$level] = "";
        foreach($select as $value){
            $userid = $value->member_id;
        $array[$level] .= $userid.',';
             self::downlines($userid, $level);
        }
```

Either way the code you posted has many mistakes. you overrule the passed variables and will always return a new array with 1 key